# Google Spreadsheet "The document cannot be modified. Perhaps it has grown too large?" error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have recently exceeded the 2 million cells of a spreadsheet recently due to a timed script adding too much external data to a sheet.

If I try and load the Spreadsheet in Chrome, Chrome crashes although it does load in Firefox. If I try to delete content in Firefox it either hangs or tells me it is "Trying to Reconnect" or that the spreadsheet is too big.

How do you get your data back?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is ... you cannot.
The only solution I found was copying and pasting chunks out of the offending sheet and pasting it into a new sheet as there appears to be no way to delete or alter any data and have it save. 
I could also copy other sheets to another spreadsheet so my functionality was intact and I assume I could have rolled back to pre 2 million cell version but I didn't pick this up for a while.

If you are running an automatic process of adding data, keep an eye on the amount of data you are storing!

Comment: I'm confused why you answered yourself immediately. Did you not want help?

Comment: I closed it immediately as I had spent a lot of time investigating how to fix my issue and wanted others to be aware of how to handle a similar situation or being able to provide an alternative process.

Comment: I would understand this IF you had found the solution, but since you didn't, it is just demoralizing, and you could be wrong. Besides, maybe someone else actually HAS found an answer, but they will be much less likely to respond if an answer has already been posted.

Comment: I would only be too happy to have a solution posted @EvSunWoodard and would bow to them. As it is a SAAS and Google constantly evolves, I see that there will be an alternative at some time. Currently I have a number of spreadsheets over the 2million cell count and getting them working would make me happy.

Answer (score 1):

You can restore from Version History. Then offload the data somewhere else and/or fix whatever is causing the spreadsheet to overflow.