# Is there any way to fix the 2 million cell limit in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace

I'm even willing to pay for a Google service, if necessary. I only need a spreadsheet with unlimited cells/storage and flexibility in using it.

Can anyone suggest a plan, if there is one?

Comment: Have you looked at spreading your data across multiple spreadsheets? Or storing some of it in another way?

Comment: What is your use case? Maybe a spreadsheet is not really what you need?

Answer (score 2):

"Unlimited" is [pie in the sky](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pie_in_the_sky) but since the current limit for cells in a spreadsheet is [five million](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44614610/1505120), there's an extra three million for you. Gratis.

And there is [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/).

Comment: Of note is the death error when your spreadsheet gets too large to be worked with. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52880742/google-sheet-api-isnt-updating-for-document-too-large https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340893/google-spreadsheet-the-document-cannot-be-modified-perhaps-it-has-grown-too-la

Answer (score 1):

As I know, there is no plan for it and no possibility to break the limit.

You just can try some optimisation:

- delete all unused columns and rows from all the TAB being used in the spreadsheet as empty cells are also counted.
- you could breakup the data into various spreadsheet workbooks...