# Google Sheet API isn't updating for document too large

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

i'm using google sheeet api to update a spreadsheet every day.

For 2 months it worked perfectly, but suddenly it stopped on update.
I tried to run it in my machine and i received the error:

> json returned "This document is too large to continue editing."

i tried some things to fix it but without sucesss. As you can see it accuses me of the document being large, but the document was as big as always. I tried to update the document writing only ONE LINE and i received the same error...

Also i tried to create a other spreadsheet to receive the complete update (that should be "too large") but it worked perfectly... ok, my code is working in other spread sheet and not in the first one...

I also tried to edit the first spreadsheet manually, but i can't, the spread sheet stays in the status 'saving' or 'reconnecting', but never saves.

Well... Yes, i can use the second spreadsheet that is working, but probably the problem will come back, so i would like to resolve this permanently.

Somebody can help me?

Comment: File>Make a copy. Use the copy. In future, try deleting revisions history through Drive-api

Comment: Thanks, but apparently there is no way to delete history.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/revisions/delete