# Google Sheets API: " badRequest: This document is too large to continue editing." on a new Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I maintain a number of fairly large Google Sheets (1-3 Million Cells) that are updated via a sheets API call appending new rows every 10-15 minutes. I've been doing this for months without incident, but over the past week have started getting

`Google::Apis::ClientError: badRequest: This document is too large to continue editing.`

errors.
Per suggestions elsewhere on Stack Overflow and in the Google API documentation, these I've made fresh copies of these sheets to clear out the version history. However, after successfully updating for just a few hours, I started to get this error again for these new sheets.

I also have sheets with less data with the same update pattern and have not seen this issue for those ones; moreover, these sheets all were originally made at different times (weeks or months apart) and have different amounts of data, so it's strange to see all these errors pop up at once, and of course even stranger to see them pop up so quickly on a brand new sheet. Is there another reason to be getting this error other than too much version history? My sheets have a large number of formulas (in tabs that all read from a core sheet) but no other real fanciness (no charts or images). In case it matters, these sheets exist in my users' Google Drives, which are part of organizations other than mine...and the old docs still live there, so is it possible that somehow the older sheets with all the version history are eating up all the space in their drives?

Thank you!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, when you clear out the version history, it works correctly for some time, an then it starts failing again? Could you please provide a copy of the spreadsheet, free of sensitive information, as well as the code you're using to update the sheet, so that this can be reproduced?

Comment: What is the textual error? Is this error shown on your app or on the Google Sheets UI? Are you using free accounts or G Suite accounts? If you are using a G Suite account have your domain admin already reported this to G Suite support?

Comment: The number of cells reported (1-3 million cells) include blank cells? How many formulas have your spreadsheet?  Do these formulas use volatile functions (RAND, NOW, INDIRECT)? Do these formulas depend on the results of other formulas? how long are the formula dependencies? Do your formulas uses open references i.e. A:A?

Answer (score 0):

> so is it possible that somehow the older sheets with all the version history are eating up all the space in their drives?

That is not possible as Google Sheets don't consume storage quota.

Related

- [Google Sheet API isn't updating for document too large](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52880742/1595451) (As of September 7, 2020, there is no answer)