# Google Sheets is too large to open and copy

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet file with large stringified JSON. File size is about 30MB, but I cannot open and copy the file.

[This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z9se7L9vztv2vZmb5zpmhq6K1nHtGAHL0_IliiR3I6s/edit?usp=sharing) is a sample file with stringifed JSON. The actual file has more than 5,000 cells and each cell contains 50,000 characters.

I had tried to open it in Google Drive, and I faild. Then I tried to open it with Google Apps Script with the code below and I failed with the error message, "Exception: Service error: Drive":

```
function test() {
  let file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  let fileName = "copy of " + file.getName();
  let id = file.makeCopy(fileName, folder).getId(); <--Error occurs here
  console.log(id);
}
```

I searched in stackoverflow before posting this question and I found the following question which might be relateded with my issue:

[Google Sheet API isn't updating for document too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52880742/google-sheet-api-isnt-updating-for-document-too-large)

Accourding to one of the replies, revision history might be affecting the performance of the file. So I tried the following code to check how many revisions are there:

```
function test() {
  let optionalArgs = {
    maxResult: 1000,
  }
  let revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId, optionalArgs).items;
  let i, id;
  console.log(revisions.length)
  for (i in revisions) {
    id = revisions[i].id;
    console.log(id);
  }
}
```

The result of the above code was that no revisions are recorded.
For Spreadsheet files, probably there are no revisions created upon edits.

So what should I do to open or copy the file then?
I would like to retrieve data in the sheet. Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have a large spreadsheet file with stringified JSON"? Is this a Google Sheets spreadsheet? How do you added the "stringified JSON"? Have you already tried to download it?

Comment: In order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet?

Comment: @Rubén Thanks for your comment. Applogies for my misunderstanding explanation. Please  check the sample spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z9se7L9vztv2vZmb5zpmhq6K1nHtGAHL0_IliiR3I6s/edit?usp=sharing).

The actual sheet has a lot more in it. Say, for example, more than 5000 cells with maximum of 50,000 charactors in each of them.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for your comment. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z9se7L9vztv2vZmb5zpmhq6K1nHtGAHL0_IliiR3I6s/edit?usp=sharing) is a link of my sample data. Like I said in my previous comment, the actual sheet has a alot more data than the sample sheet. Please take a look and let me know your idea.

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. When I tested your sample Spreadsheet using you above script in your question, no error occurs. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. Can I ask you about the detailed flow for replicating your issue?

Comment: @Tanaike If the data contains a large amount of data, it gets time-consuming. For example, a simple SpreadsheetApp.openById method times out for my actual file. Sample code works just fine and I just wanted to show what the spreadsheet with stringified JSON is, as other guy asked me.